# css designation < >

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Is there a way to use CSS to specify that every time the 'less than symbol'(to the right of the M on the keyboard) or the 'more than symbol' shows up in the text it should be replaced with the actual words 'less than' or 'more than', respectively ?

Comment: What do you need this for? You might be able to use JavaScript.

Comment: No but you can do it with javascript.

Comment: [This page](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/07/how-to-find-and-replace-text-dynamically-via-javascript/) shows you how to do search and replace with javascript

Answer (score 4):

CSS cannot act on (cannot modify, that is) the text content of a webpage, so no it cannot do what you're asking.  CSS can only affect presentation and styling and in this case, would require actual text replacement, which CSS cannot do.

You can, however, do this with JavaScript, especially if you have specific DOM elements in the document you wish to target. Something like this may do the trick in a rudimentary way, but wouldn't account for a lack of spaces before or after the symbol:

```
var node = document.getElementById("somenode");
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace("&lt;", "less than");
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace("&gt;", "more than");
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot do this (or anything like it)